# passing data from jsp to servlet return null

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets, authentication

I am having trouble with my Lecturer login form. This is my login form (JSP file) for lecturers which I combine with the admin login form (index.jsp):

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="thumbnail"><img src="images/schedule_icon.png"/></div>
    <form action="lecturerLogin" class="register-form">
        <input type="text" name="lecturerID" placeholder="Lecturer ID"/>
        <input type="password" name="lecturerPassword" placeholder="Password"/>
        <button>Login</button>
        <p class="message">Forgot password?<a href="#">Recover here</a></p>
    </form>
    <form action="adminLogin" class="login-form">
        <input type="text" name="adminname" placeholder="Admin Name"/>
        <input type="password" name="adminpassword" placeholder="Password"/>
        <button>Login</button>
        <p class="message">Not an admin? <a href="#">Login here</a></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"> 
  <display-name>myapp</display-name>   
  <servlet>   
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>   
    <servlet-class>CSP600.LoginServlet</servlet-class> 
  </servlet>   
  <servlet-mapping>   
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>   
    <url-pattern>/adminLogin</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping> 
  <servlet>   
    <servlet-name>LoginLecturerServlet</servlet-name>   
    <servlet-class>CSP600.LoginLecturerServlet</servlet-class> 
  </servlet>   
  <servlet-mapping>   
    <servlet-name>LoginLecturerServlet</servlet-name>   
    <url-pattern>/lecturerLogin</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>    
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>  
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

This is my Servlet (using doGet):

```
try {
    LecturerBean lecturer = new LecturerBean();
    lecturer.setLecturerID(request.getParameter("lecturerid"));
    lecturer.setLecturerPassword(request.getParameter("lecturerpassword"));
    lecturer = LecturerDAO.lecturerlogin(lecturer);
    if (lecturer.isValid()) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("currentSessionUser", lecturer);
        response.sendRedirect("homeLecturer.jsp"); // logged-in page
    }
    else {
        response.sendRedirect("invalidLogin.jsp"); // error page
    }
}
catch (Throwable theException) {
    System.out.println(theException);
}
```

I have used the same code for admin login (I changed the necessary parts, of course) and it works perfectly fine. However, the input data from the JSP file are not passed for an unknown reason. Thus, it returns NULL to beans and DAO. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 lecturer.setLecturerID(request.getParameter("lecturerid"));
lecturer.setLecturerPassword(request.getParameter("lecturerpassword"));
```

to

```
 lecturer.setLecturerID(request.getParameter("lecturerID"));
lecturer.setLecturerPassword(request.getParameter("lecturerPassword"));
```

Comment: yeah.. these kind of mistakes happen a lot.. silly but time consuming..glad i could help.